# Почему кнопка не работает?

Tags: python, aiogram

```
but_menu = InlineKeyboardButton(text='назад', callback_data='nazad')
greet_but = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(but_menu)

@bot.callback_query_handler(text='nazad')
async def zapros(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.answer("Сделайте свой выбор!", reply_markup=client.greet_menu)#перенаправляет к другой клавиатуре
    await callback.answer()
```

После нажатия на кнопку, ничего не происходит

Comment: Покажите как вы создаете `bot`

Comment: Но скорее всего ваш `bot` это диспатчер(я надеюсь (и также надеюсь что вы его переименуете)), потому я догадываюсь что у вас есть `callback_query_handler` выше, который сьедает в себя этот колбек.

Comment: bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

В этом файле, да и вообще во всем коде всего один 'callback_query_handler '

Comment: А замените на `@dp.callback_query_handler(text='nazad')`

Comment: суть в том, что у меня не один файл. На самом деле у меня в самом низу такое написано: `dp.callback_query_handler(zapros, text='nazad')`

Comment: Дайте весь код, я ничего не понял

Comment: да уже не нужно) Жаль конечно что у меня не получается с инлайн кнопками от слова совсем, но зато такие чудеса творю с клавиатурными кнопками)

Comment: Как это не нужно? Удалите тогда вопрос свой вообще, а если задали вопрос то будьте любезны соглашаться с требованиями тех людей, которые прорываются вам помогать. А вообще предоставить минимальный воспроизводимый пример, это требования этого ресурса.